# Update Mysql tables upon inserting into another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, the first tables is a transactions table which has records of all transactions, and the second table is the savings table which has the total of all transactions amounts.

```
INSERT INTO `groupsavings`.`transactions` 
        (`transactions_id`, `shareholder_id`, `transactions_type`, 
        `transactions_date`, `amount`, `pool`) 
   VALUES  (NULL, '1', 'credit', '2019-01-01', '100', 'poolone');

INSERT INTO `groupsavings`.`transactions` 
        (`transactions_id`, `shareholder_id`, `transactions_type`, 
        `transactions_date`, `amount`, `pool`) 
   VALUES (NULL, '1', 'credit', '2019-01-01', '50', 'poolone');


UPDATE `groupsavings`.`saving_pool` 
    SET `pool_value` = '100' 
WHERE `saving_pool`.`Pool_name` = 'poolone';

UPDATE `groupsavings`.`saving_pool` 
    SET `pool_value` = '150' 
WHERE `saving_pool`.`Pool_name` = 'poolone';
```

I want the savings table to cumulatively add to the savings table upon inserting into transactions table.

Comment: Where is your java code that you tried to do this job?

Comment: `SET pool_value = pool_value + 100` then  `SET pool_value = pool_value + 50`  And also set the default value for `pool_value` to zero not NULL

Comment: Have you considered making the savings table a materialized view instead of a table? Also, this doesn't appear to be `java` related at all.

Comment: Have you heard of and rejected triggers or have you not heard of triggers?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to automatically update the savings table with the sum of the current amount in transaction table.

You can try this method assuming you named your database connection variables like this ( Connection con, PreparedStatement pst, ResultSet rs)

```
public void insertt(){
String trans_id = "";
String share_id = "";
String trans_type = "";
String trans_date = "";
String amt = "";
String poolname = "";

try{
String sql = " INSERT INTO groupsavings.transactions (transactions_id, shareholder_id, transactions_type, transactions_date, amount, pool)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, trans_id);
pst.setString(2, share_id);
pst.setString(3, trans_type);
pst.setString(4, trans_date);
pst.setString(5, amt);
pst.setString(6, poolname);

pst.execute();

String sql2 = "select sum(amount) from groupsavings.transactions WHERE saving_pool.pool_name = ’"+poolname+"' ";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
int sum = 0;
while(rs.next()){
sum = rs.getInt(0);
String newpool = String.valueOf(sum);
}
String sql3 ="UPDATE groupsavings.saving_pool SET pool_value = ’"+newpool+"' WHERE saving_pool.pool_name =’"+poolname+"' ";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
pst.execute();

}


catch(SQLException e){}
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your post - and check it better. As far as I see, the variable `con` is not defined

Comment: con, pst and rs are Connection variables. Connection con, PreparedStatement pst, ResultSet rs

Comment: What language is this? OP has not tagged anything but mysql.

Comment: Yet, `con` is not defined within that method

Comment: Oh that's java, my bad. I didn't look at the tag